# React Redirect Post

Tags: jquery, reactjs, post

I am trying make this call where url is the base domain name and model is the object being passed into the POST but for react. (Do not want to use jquery in my react application):

```
$.redirect(url + "external-entrance", model, "POST");
```

The form information is being sent to a third party where they are calculating the information from the form and displaying information to me on their site. In my current solution, I am using refs to submit the form. However, I want to use state since I can validate/mask the fields better and also send the information to my own backend. But when I uue state I cannot do a post redirect like in form `ref="form"` `method="post"` `action="url"`, using axios post then `windows.location.href` it just takes me to the link but doesn't POST to it.

```
import React from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'
import { H3, P } from '../../components/StyledHeading'
import Button from '../../components/Button'


class ContactForm extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
  super(props)
  this.state = {
    firstName: '',
    lastName: '',
    email: '',
    phone: '',
    zipCode: '',
    errors: [],
  }
  this.textInput = React.createRef();
}

_handleSubmit = evt => {
  evt.preventDefault()
  const payload = {
    "first_name": "Thomas",
    "last_name": "Edison",
    "email": "edison@email.com",
    "phone": "555-555-5355",
    "zip_code": 239062,
  }
  this.refs.myForm.submit();
}

render() {
  return (
    <Container>
      <form ref="myForm" method="post" action="https://externalsite.co/external-entrance">
        <H3>Ready to reserve your spot?</H3>
        <P className="subtitle">Fill out the form below and we&rsquo;ll get in touch soon.</P>
        <div className="inputFieldSection">
          <label>
            First Name:
            <input
              type="text"
              ref={this.textInput}
              disabled={isSending}
              name="firstName"
              placeholder="Thomas"/>
          </label>
          <label>
            Last Name:
            <input
            type="text"
            ref={this.textInput}
            disabled={isSending}
            name="lastName"
            placeholder="Edison"/>
        </label>
        <label>
          Phone Number:
          <input
            type="text"
            ref={this.textInput}
            disabled={isSending}
            name="phoneNumber"
            placeholder="555-555-5555"/>
        </label>
        <label>
          Email address:
          <input
            type="text"
            ref={this.textInput}
            disabled={isSending}
            name="emailAddress"
            placeholder="edison@email.com"/>
        </label>
        <input type="hidden" ref={this.textInput} name="zipCode" value={29006}/>
      </div>
      <Button color={Color.secondaryColor} onClick={this._handleSubmit}>Submit My Reservation</Button>
    </form>
  </Container>
)
}
}

export default ContactForm
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of things that I believe you are doing the wrong way in my estimations.

- There's no need to create a reference of the **form** as well as adding the ***"post"*** and ***"action"*** tags to the form. You just need to set the ***"onSubmit"*** property to a function that you will use to make the API call `<form onSubmit={this._handleSubmit}>`
- Based on my first point, you need to set the ***type*** of the button inside the form you will use to submit your form to `<button type="submit"></button>`.
- When declaring a function if you do not use ES6, you will have to bind the function in the class constructor (the case of your ***"SendLead()"*** function) like `this.SendLead = this.SendLead.bind(this)`
- It will be better to save the form inputs on the class state, that way it will be easier to perform validations or pass those to another component or whatever.
- Instead of using a hidden input field you could set that value on the state in the constructor of your class.
- Since we are saving the input fields values in the state, you need to add a function to the ***"onChange"*** event of each input field. `onChange={this._handleInputChange}`

Those are the main things I could point to in your code. I tweaked yours a little bit to make it work but basically I just did what I mentioned above.

```
import React from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'
// import { H3, P } from '../../components/StyledHeading'
// import Button from '../../components/Button'


class ContactForm extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      firstName: '',
      lastName: '',
      email: '',
      phone: '',
      zipCode: 29006,
      errors: [],
    }
  }

  SendLead = payload => {
    const URL = "http://localhost:3001/v1"
    const authToken = "Token token=5e2pJ5P234234123"
    const config = { "headers": { Authorization: authToken } }
    const bodyParams = payload

    axios.post(`${URL}/leads`, bodyParams, config)
      .then(res => console.log({res}))
      .catch(error => {
        console.log({error})
        this.setState({
          errors: error.response.data,
        })
      })

  }

  _handleInputChange = e => 
    this.setState({
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value
    })


  _handleSubmit = evt => {
    evt.preventDefault()
    const {
      firstName,
      lastName,
      email,
      phone,
      zipCode
    } = this.state;

    const payload = {
      "first_name": firstName,
      "last_name": lastName,
      "email": email,
      "phone": phone,
      "zip_code": zipCode,
    }
    this.SendLead(payload)
  }

  render() {
    const {
      firstName,
      lastName,
      email,
      phone,
      zipCode
    } = this.state;

    return (
      <form onSubmit={this._handleSubmit}>
        <h3>Ready to reserve your spot?</h3>
        <p className="subtitle">Fill out the form below and we&rsquo;ll get in touch soon.</p>
        <div className="inputFieldSection">
          <label>
            First Name:
            <input
              type="text"
              value={firstName}
              onChange={this._handleInputChange}
              // disabled={isSending}
              name="firstName"
              placeholder="Thomas" />
          </label>
          <label>
            Last Name:
            <input
              type="text"
              value={lastName}
              onChange={this._handleInputChange}
              // disabled={isSending}
              name="lastName"
              placeholder="Edison" />
          </label>
          <label>
            Phone Number:
              <input
              type="text"
              value={phone}
              onChange={this._handleInputChange}
              // disabled={isSending}
              name="phone"
              placeholder="555-555-5555"
            />
          </label>

          <label>
            Email address:
              <input
              type="text"
              value={email}
              onChange={this._handleInputChange}

              // disabled={isSending}
              name="email"
              placeholder="edison@email.com"
            />
          </label>
          <input type="hidden" name="zipCode" value={29006} />
        </div>
        <button type="submit">Submit My Reservation</button>
      </form>
    )
  }
}

export default ContactForm
```

Comment: @andre-gomez Did this help?